# Function which types optional argument only if it is provided

Tags: tex-core

The idea is to create a command with an optional argument that would only write it if it IS provided.

I've tried simply using [] as an optional argument when defining the command:

```
\newcommand{\partc}[2][]{{
    \bigskip
    \noindent
    \hspace{-0.25cm}
    \fontsize{11pt}{5}
    \color{sectioncolor}
    \textbf{#2}}

    {
    \noindent
    \normalcolor
    \textbf{#1}}
    \bigskip
    }
```

but it seems to still type an empty line (which actually seems logical). I've also tried to modify it with `if` like that:

```
\newcommand{\partc}[2][]{{
    \bigskip
    \noindent
    \hspace{-0.25cm}
    \fontsize{11pt}{5}
    \color{sectioncolor}
    \textbf{#2}}

    {
    \if#1
    \noindent
    \normalcolor
    \textbf{#1}}
    \bigskip
    \fi
    }
```

but it simply does not ever write the optional argument.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: you are missing `%` from the ends of lines so will add spurious space also `\fontsize{11pt}{5}` specifies 11pt text placed on baselines 5pt apart, which can not work, what did you intend there?  you can use `\ifx\relax#1\relax` which is true if #1 is empty, as in that case it is `\ifx\relax\relax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `\hspace{-0.25}` is supposed to do.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{sectioncolor}{red!80!blue}

\newcommand{\partc}[2][]{%
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}%
  \noindent\hspace*{-0.25cm}%
  {\color{sectioncolor}\fontsize{11}{13.2}\bfseries#2\par}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \noindent\textbf{#1}%
  \fi
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}%
}

\begin{document}

\partc{abc}

\partc[def]{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I fixed `\fontsize{11pt}{5}` to something more meaningful: you surely don't want a baselineskip of 5pt when the font size is 11pt.